# a webservice for finding the flights by country

Tags: air-travel, online-resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I do a “broad” search for flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/730/how-can-i-do-a-broad-search-for-flights)

Do you know any webapplication/service which allow me to specify the contry/state for destinations and arivals and it gives you all the flights from all the cities/airports of that contries/areas.

I plan to travel in Europe!

Comment: Not sure it's a 100% match, but I think good answers to this would likely be answers to mine as well.

Comment: I'm also not sure that this is really a duplicate...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might try [Skyscanner](http://www.skyscanner.com/). It's not a perfect match, but it's one of the only sites I know that allows you to search country instead individual airports or cities. It can match everything from a given country to anywhere else in the world.

It doesn't have 100% complete results, but it might give you an idea of what to look for. It also doesn't always show the best prices, so when you find an airport and date combination that looks good for you, use that data on another flight search tool to see if you can spot a better deal.