# What is the cheapest way to get from EU to India by plane?

Tags: air-travel, europe, india, eu

What's the flight or flights that regularly connect an European Union country with India for less money? My research has showed that Air Arabia was a good option some years ago when connected Athens with a lot indian cities through Sharja, but now this route is no longer operated.

Comment: From where in EU to where in India? Please clarify because it does make a difference.

Comment: Also, it depends too much on when a person is traveling. You didn't say what season, what month, even what year. Regular flights don't have the same prices during the year and mostly depend on a date of travel, how many tickets was sold and whether you want a direct or connecting flight. Just FYI, I found a return flight a couple of days ago from Croatia to Delhi via Moscow for $560 (note it's dollars, not euros). This means that the prices from Western Europe can only be lower...

Comment: I think that this question cannot be answered completely i.e. final answer cannot be given because the prices change almost on daily basis.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee: Anywhere in EU to anywhere in India. It's easy: in Europe using low cost companies any country is 50 € away from any other country. When I visit India I'll go for a couple of months so I don't care to go to this or this other city, I'll visit all country.

Comment: @rlesko: Yes, it depends, I'm looking for the cheapest regular flight on the year. I have availability all year to travel. Just need a good price :)

Comment: @Ivan - and I'm telling you that you can't get the right answer. We can tell you the prices for next 6 to 8 months but it can happen that the prices for that exact same flight (on the same day, same time) drop in a month or two or more. as I said in one of my answers earlier, I bought a ticket for Delhi for $734 and that was a "tipping point" for that flight so the next available ticket was going for 600-something bucks. It really is either luck or meticulous research every couple of days.

Comment: Try Kayak's [Buzz](http://www.kayak.com/buzz) (best price results by other travelers) and then use `Price alert` on the left that will send you emails when prices drop!

Comment: @rlesko: Yes, you are right, but you know that sometimes there are airlines like Air Arabia which I mentioned in the question that have a regular price that "in general" (of course, not always) is cheaper than any other. This company has finished the flight I wanted to buy and my question (perhaps bad written, sorry) is "is there any other company like this?"

Comment: See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/730/how-can-i-do-a-broad-search-for-flights

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure whether it is the cheapest, but [Emirates](http://www.emirates.com) currently has [offers](http://www.emirates.com/es/english/destinations_offers/special_offers/special_fares/special_fares.aspx) from many European cities to Delhi, Kolkata, Bangalore, Mumbai or Chennai for 550-600 Euros return. You have to change in Dubai.

You can fly from Madrid to Delhi on February 24th for 464 Euros.