# How can I find cheap international airfares from Chicago?

Tags: air-travel, budget, airlines, international-travel, chicago

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I do a “broad” search for flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/730/how-can-i-do-a-broad-search-for-flights)

What are reliable ways to find cheap international airfare? My husband and I live in Chicago and want to travel, but we're not that picky about our destination.

Are there websites for this? I know my high school Spanish teacher used to rave about a website that sold discount airfare to Latin America, but I can't for the life of me remember what it was called. Does anyone know of one, or of similar sites for other parts of the world?

Or are there airlines that serve Chicago (or other U.S. cities, we may be willing/able to get to the departure city) that sell relatively inexpensive tickets?

Comment: Beth welcome to travel.SE.  Please visit the [FAQ](http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq) to get some feel about asking  good questions and getting answers because as it stands right now the community won't be able to answer this in any meaningful way.

Comment: Thanks, Karlson. I understand that it is fairly broad, and also that it might elicit a "list" kind of response. However, I do not understand how to improve the question. Is there a place on the site for asking for such feedback?

Comment: In general the better way to ask would be: I am looking to do this in Latin America where can I go to do it and how can I get there for <$1k by [air, land, sea] from Chicago?  Your question assumes we know what you like and don't like.  We don't.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Kayak explore](http://kayak.com/explore), one of my personal favorites for finding cheap airfare to wherever is cheap