# Why is Melbourne-Singapore-Melbourne return flight is costlier than Singapore-Melbourne-Singapore return flight?

Tags: air-travel, singapore, fares, melbourne, mel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do return flight costs vary depending on the country of origin?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6304/why-do-return-flight-costs-vary-depending-on-the-country-of-origin)

I am trying to book a return flight from Melbourne to Singapore, but it is costing me AUD 999, i.e. almost 60% more than Singapore to Melbourne return flight (which is SGD 800 i.e. approx AUD 600). I am not able to understand the reason behind this.

Both the flights MEL-SIN-MEL and SIN-MEL-SIN involves one flight each from Singapore to Melbourne and Melbourne to Singapore, the only difference is the order of flights.

Note: Both the prices are normal, regular prices and not a sale price.

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Duplcate of http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6304/why-do-return-flight-costs-vary-depending-on-the-country-of-origin