# I pay triple the price originating a flight from US, (L.A.- Amsterdam) versus the opposite (Am-L.A)

Tags: air-travel

I heard that the reason why we pay almost triple the price from a flight originating in the US is because the US charges over $700 in taxes on an international flight.
How to avoid this?