# Are there any websites that will find cheapest flights over a large date range?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I do a “broad” search for flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/730/how-can-i-do-a-broad-search-for-flights)

I need to go to Florida over the next 4 months.  I don't really care when it is (i have flexibility).  I want to find a site where i can say:

- I want a 5 day trip
- I want to go any time in the next 5 months
- Typical flight constraints (non stop, etc)

Go find me the cheapest flight

Does this exist?