# Travel site that found the lowest-price tickets from your current location

Tags: online-resources, bookings

Some time ago I had a bookmark to an awesome travel site, which I've lost. I'm hoping someone else used it.  The site was very minimal. You told it where you currently are, and it showed you the cheapest flights either in the next three days, or the whole month, from your current city. Ie, you didn't specify where you wanted to *go*, you specified where you *were*, and it told you where you could go.

If it helps narrow it down, I remember the website had a rotating set of background photos of various places, and the UI was very minimal and sat in a small rounded rectangle in the screen center.

Ie, the UI was a nice photo, and then in the very center of the screen, a small rounded-rectangle for search and results.  It was very distinctive.

It was a nice approach to travel planning, leading to spontaneous trips, quite unlike all other search sites I've used, and I'd like to find it again.

> **This question is not a duplicate of "[How can I do a broad search for flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/730/how-can-i-do-a-broad-search-for-flights)"** I am not looking for a general broad search
>   engine. I am seeking a *specific travel/search site* with *specific
>   and unusual functionality* that is *more specific than in that
>   question* and is *not answered by any answers in that question.*
>
> I hate to sound snippy, but this should have been obvious from reading
>   both questions.  (For example, where in that question does it mention the site I'm looking for? I'll answer: it doesn't. This specific site had functionality unlike any other site that I know of, and better than those mentioned in the other question.) This specific site did some cool stuff, which is why I ant to find this one, not a common, well-known one. Please reopen, and **please read** both questions and
>   answers to verify this, as I believe you should have before closing.

Comment: @Ankur Banerjee: Please reopen; you closed mistakenly. I explained why in the question, though I think you should have read the question before closing.

Comment: Click on the question you are linked to. Read the different answers highly upvoted. The third links to Skyscanner: www.skyscanner.com. This does EXACTLY what you describe. We are not in your mind nor in your browser so maybe we will not find back the bookmark you had. But before yelling that you disagree with close votes, read.

Comment: I read. *Skyscanner does not have this functionality*, nor is it this specific useful site. I'm sure knowing about this site would be very useful for other members of the community (if they're travelers as opposed to just booking holidays.)

Comment: Now, maybe I'm not explaining the site's functionality well, in which case please ask for clarifications. I'm always happy to do so :) But closing is not appropriate.

Comment: The functionality I understood is, enter an origin city, choose a day or period of time, and the site gives you a list of destination sorted by price. Here is the request I just did: http://www.skyscanner.fr/transport/vols-de/lys/janvier-2014/janvier-2014/vols-les-moins-chers-de-lyon-saint-exupery-en-janvier-2014.html?rtn=1 starting from Lyon (France) any time in January. And I get a list of destination countries, sorted by increasing price of air ticket. If this is not what you expect, edit your post.

Comment: I just read your question, thought 'huh, sounds just like skyscanner, I use it for just that' before even looking at the duplicate question.  It's hard to ask for clarifications if we're not able to see any difference - could you perhaps explain what Skyscanner can't do that your other sites does? Because as the question stands, closing as duplicate seems very appropriate :/

Comment: It wasn't Bing Travel, was it?

Comment: Sure :) First, this site did *only* this - it is its only functionality, and it was very good at it. (I actually didn't know Skyscanner did that, and it doesn't return the results I remember this site returning. IMO it's not nearly as good!) Second, even if Skyscanner has similar functionality, we don't exist on this site to spruik only one company, do we? Why is a question seeking a different known-to-be-good site closed as a duplicate of Skyscanner? I tried to describe the site, its layout (since it's memorable) etc as well as I could - I don't know how anyone could mistake the two.

Comment: No, not Bing. Good suggestion though. I got the impression it was quite a small company. I only came across it by accident, and lost the bookmark in a hard drive crash a couple of months ago. I'm asking here since I can't be the only travel.so user to have used it... and if I am, and we can figure out what it was, it will be a useful addition to travel.so's answers since it was such a cool site.

Comment: Is it seriously about guessing what bookmark was stored in the browser of the OP?

Comment: Concert tickets? Bus tickets? I believe you're missing a tag to narrow this down.

Comment: For trying to locate a webapp from a description you could probably try our sister site, [web apps stack exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it!  [Drungli](http://www.drungli.com/).

[image: Screenshot of Drungli]

Excellent site.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Adioso and Skyscanner that were already mentioned, there are a few that do this that come to mind. Your description sounds very much like DoHop's "Away".

- [DoHop's Away](http://www.dohop.com/away/)
- [Kayak Explore](http://www.kayak.com/explore/)
- [FareCompare's Getaway Map](http://www.farecompare.com/maps/)
- [Skypicker](http://skypicker.com/)

Comment: Another I've used is [Momondo](http://www.momondo.com/).

Comment: DoHop does look similar!  Some of the sites people are posting here look like clones of each other... curious. But I've bookmarked that site to return to.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This sounds quite a bit like [Adioso](http://adioso.com/).

Comment: Nice idea, but it seems as if Adioso just tries to find the cheapest ticket to a fixed set of destinations instead of actually searching for the cheapest destinations. Besides from that, of the three cheapest tickets currently found for flights from Munich, none of the tickets can actually be booked for the price shown by Adioso. From the web site, it is also impossible to tell if the price e.g. includes check-in luggage or not.

Comment: Mileage clearly varies. I've used Adioso on multiple occasions for intra-Europe travel. Each time, quoted ticket prices were available for booking and each time the quoted price was the available cheapest option (meaning, with all fees but without luggage).

Comment: Thankyou, but it wasn't Adioso. It had a much lighter UI, and seemed to search more or different airlines. I updated the question to describe the site's look a bit more.