# Find cheap flights with timeconstrains like any week-end

Tags: flight-search-engines

I want to do certain trips when I can get it cheaply, for example cheap flight Friday evening and the following Sunday evening.
(So not a particular week-end but the cheapest week-end in a period of a few months)

How can I search for this, and keep monitoring for for example the next 2 months?

This is typically between 2 European countries, sometimes with inland connections on one side.  Sometimes the return is from a slightly different airport.

Sometimes (like when I want to leave from work) I typically want a god combination of cheapness/directness in a time-period.

Other-times, like Sunday evening return i want a good combination of lateness, cheapness and directness.

Any help to formulate this better is appreciated.

(Airports flexibility is not important, so proposed duplicate is not a duplicate at all).

If this cant be done directly, I might want to bookmark searches.  Then bookmarking should be possible, and it should be easy to create a new search from another one.

Comment: Not a duplicate at all.  My airports are quite fixed.

Comment: The answers there cover your scenario as well.

Comment: Which one?  I cant see anything relevant in the top answers.  (Without checking the websites)

Comment: All of the answers do what you're looking for: Kayak, Skyscanner, ITA Matrix.

Comment: I looked at Skyskanner, and I would have to enter each week-end separately.

Comment: Sorry, Skyscanner only does a whole month. But Kayak can do weekends.

Comment: Kayak let me enter the search criteria - Thanks.  At first look the results doesn't look good.  Also, different departure return departure airport seems not possible.

Comment: Very related (if not duplicate): http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42721/searching-for-flights-to-anywhere-in-narrow-time-frame

Comment: That one is for specific week-ends.  NOT DUPLICATE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[azair](http://www.azair.com/) has this functionality (see the advanced options).

[image]