# Which websites allow "search by country" for a flight?

Tags: air-travel, budget, europe, online-resources, planning

I came to know about [Whichbudget](http://whichbudget.com/), it's a website that allow search for flights by country. I mean you just enter from like "Germany" and to like "Belgium" and you get best offers from all airports between the two countries. That is great. And I was able to arrange a good-price trip to Brussels.

Now I want to arrange another trip to Turkey, but Whichbudget is not helping much this time. And I can't find any other websites that allow "search by country".

**Update:** ***Not duplicate to*** [How can I do a “broad” search for flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/730/how-can-i-do-a-broad-search-for-flights) as his question is broad to the extent of a state. But my question is broad to the extent of a whole country + less price + "Any Time". If anyone checks [whichbudget](http://www.whichbudget.com/), he'll understand what I'm saying. Especially that whichbudget allows "Any Time" option, not just +/-3 days.

**Does anyone know more similar websites?**

Comment: Very related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27100/cheapest-flight-to-anywhere-at-any-given-time

Comment: Just to clarify, you want a site that allows you enter an entire country for both the origin and destination? Or only the destination? Many more sites offer the latter than the former.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Skyscanner](http://www.skyscanner.com/) allows what you're looking for. Just type the country of origin and destination. It even allows you to set the destination as all the world instead of country.

In Skyscanner you will also be allowed to make broad searches regarding time. You can specify the time windows of your flight as specific days, but also as a month (eg.: departing in July). The results will be presented in form of a price calendar (or graph) and you can check the cheapest days.

**Note:**

[Momondo](https://www.momondo.com/) also allows this now.

Comment: This is a great site. What are other sites like this?

Answer (score 9):

[Google flights](http://flights.google.com) can do this, you can select airports, places, countries, continents or just "Everywhere", you can also select interests (eg, Outdoor, food, etc)

You can set a price range, and then see on the map where you can go. I spent a day in Copenhagen for about £20-30 thanks to this.

(and it also used to have a really nice bar chart for each destination showing the price over a time period for route, but they seem to have got rid of this feature)

Comment: Google Flights only lets you enter an entire country for the destination, not for the origin. OP seems to want it for both but it's not totally clear so I asked for clarification.

Answer (score 8):

I am a fan of [Adioso](http://adioso.com), it allows you do all of what you've asked for, the only catch is you have to specify at least a city in the departure field, but any other field is capable of accepting broad values.

You can specify a time, or chose "any time". For the destination, you can specify a city, a country, etc. You can then sort the results according to the price, it has that option.

Comment: I'm a fan of Adioso too but its lack of "from entire country" is a major point for my style of travel now that SkyScanner does let you do that. I'm pretty sure SkyScanner didn't used to have this feature.

Answer (score 4):

[WhichAirline](http://www.whichairline.com/) has a similar functionality to whichbudget as far as I can see. You can enter countries but it might give you an error that this search is too broad, in that case it might help to search to "Anywhere" and then sort the results by country.

Also [Kiwi.com](https://www.kiwi.com/de/) (formerly Skypicker) might be useful. You can do countries or draw circles on a map for departure/destination area which could turn out even more handy. For a few more details [see another answer of mine here.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/62685/32134) [@Underyx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43426/underyx) gets credit for [this handy example.](https://us.skypicker.com/cheap-flights-from-germany-to-turkey/departure-12-05-2016-11-11-2016)

You might also want to look to [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/) and focus on the flight answers.

Comment: Actually, it's totally possible to do country searches on Skypicker, see here: https://us.skypicker.com/cheap-flights-from-germany-to-turkey/departure-12-05-2016-11-11-2016

Comment: You got it :)

By the way, another thing that might be useful on Skypicker for this use case is the 'time to stay' searching; not only can you say you are interested in flights departing anytime, but you can also specify that you want a return flight e.g. 5 to 10 days after that.

Comment: @Underyx, mts, skypicker is now kiwi??

Comment: That's right, rebranded to Kiwi.com last year.