# How to get to Mendocino CA from Seattle?

Tags: air-travel, usa, routes

Options I know of are driving there, or flying to someplace where one might rent a car, and then driving. The closest place I know I can fly to is San Francisco, which is about 4 hours' drive away. I see there are little airports near or in Mendocino... is it possible to schedule a flight there? At reasonable expense? Or is Oakland and/or driving self the best way?

Comment: 'The best' way? What's best? fastest, cheapest...?

Comment: I'm interested in faster-but-comparably-priced ways to get there, thinking probably that would mean a flight into someplace closer to Mendocino than San Francisco.

Comment: Did you try searching for flights to the smaller airports nearer your destination? eg doing a broad search for all airports within x miles of there?

Comment: As @Gagravarr suggests, use tools such as those described in the question [How can I do a “broad” search for flights?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/730/how-can-i-do-a-broad-search-for-flights)

Comment: @Gagravarr I didn't know what to use to do that. I tried using Google Maps to find airports, but I didn't know how to find commercial flights to/from them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rome2Rio [suggests](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Seattle/Mendocino) you fly to Santa Rosa, which is well north of the Bay Area, and almost halfway between San Francisco and Mendocino.

Alaska Airlines flies from SEA-STS, though for most flights you'll have a layover in PDX (I'd try to avoid this if possible). Direct flights are available, but apparently not every day of the week. And this is [the only commercial airline serving that airport](http://www.sonomacountyairport.org/alaska-airlines-sonoma-county-airport-sts-fly-nonstop-los-angeles-portland-san-diego-and-seattle).

After that you should [rent a car](http://www.kayak.com/Cheap-Santa-Rosa-Car-Rentals.27165.cars.ksp) for the much shorter 100-mile drive. While there are buses, [the one you would need](http://mendocinotransit.org/routes/route-65/) runs only once a day and the one daily direct flight arrives after it leaves.