# Price search for a weekend flight to a specific city over a few months

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines

I am trying to book flights for a weekend trip from Warsaw to Athens. I would like to fly after work on Friday and return Sunday evening, so I have pretty well defined flight times in terms of weekdays. I can even come up with my preferred flight numbers. The thing that is flexible is the choice of weekend. Is there a tool that could automate this search, i.e. display a table of all the weekends in some range with corresponding prices?

NOTE: This is a much more narrowed problem than a broad search, and as it turns out (see answers) it has a dedicated solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do a "broad" search for flights?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/730/how-can-i-do-a-broad-search-for-flights)

Comment: It's a bit more specific than a broad search - it's a weekend search. And this is a feature of some search websites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used to use Skyscanner for weekend searches, but can't seem to find their feature for it any more.

However, [Kayak](http://kayak.com) does this now.  For example, [a search for all weekend flights from Sydney to Canberra for Feb 2016](https://www.kayak.com.au/flights/SYD-CBR,nearby/weekend/2016-02-Fri-PM-Sun).

To do, go to kayak.com, choose flights, put in your details and select 'Show Flexible Dates', and then 'Weekends', and follow the instructions.

Comment: Looks like exactly something I need, thanks! The only issue is that Ryanair's systems seem not to be working very well this afternoon.

Comment: Mark - you might want to clarify to click on "Show Flexible Dates" as a step there.  Weekends isn't visible initially.

Comment: @Joe done, thx!