# How to search for weekend flights?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, bookings, planning, flight-search-engines

I'd like to search for flights departing either Fri PM or Sat AM, and returning either Sun PM or Mon AM.

In Google Flights, this requires 4 separate searches. Is there another site/tool that allows such a search?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "another site/tool that allows such a search". All airlines offer search options where you can input your desired departure and return dates.

Comment: @MichaelC. My desired departure date is "between 6pm Friday and 12pm Saturday", and my desired return date is "between 6pm Sunday and 9am Monday". Google Flights does support flexible departure/return dates, and does support specific departure/return times, but these times apply to all days (for example, Friday or Saturday, between 2pm and 5pm).

Comment: Yes, many. For example kayak.com allows you to simultaneously search +/- 3 days so that within just one search you get 49 different combinations of departure and return dates.

Comment: @SheikPaul  I know, Google Flights also allows for this. But can you simultaneously search for "depart Fri PM or Sat AM" + "return Sun PM or Sat AM"?

Comment: I recommend looking at the answer provided [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/82061). I found [AZair](http://AZair.com) to be a great resource due to fine-grained control over travel days-of-the-week and what is possible to control for time of departure. Happy travels!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Price search for a weekend flight to a specific city over a few months](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58087/price-search-for-a-weekend-flight-to-a-specific-city-over-a-few-months)

Comment: @choster Does't seem to be a duplicate of that question. This question appears to be "I want to travel on a specific weekend but I don't really mind what time"; the other is "I want to travel at specific times but I don't really mind what weekend."

Answer (score 14):

On [Matrix Airfare Search](http://matrix.itasoftware.com) you have the option of searching for flexible dates. In my case I was able to search for flights from LHR to FRA leaving Friday and/or day before and coming back Monday on this day only - but you can change that to be the day before/after. You can also specify what time of day (early morning, midday, etc.)

[image]

EDIT: OP is looking for a combination of different times frames on different dates. Just click on the "Time bars" after your search and you can see a visual of the different dates and times. 
[image]

Comment: I know, Google Flights also allows for this. But can you simultaneously search for "depart Fri PM or Sat AM" + "return Sun PM or Sat AM"?

Comment: thanks, but I still wasn't able to perform my desired search. I tried "depart Sat AM or the day before", and the search results included flights departing Sat AM or Fri AM. http://imgur.com/a/LQq11

Comment: @gberger That's what it's supposed to do. You asked for Saturday AM and the day before (i.e. Friday AM). You can add in more times to get a wider range of time frames.

Comment: right, but I can't configure it to search for Sat AM or Fri PM.

Comment: I edited again, please see revised answer. I really can't teach you how to use the tool, but if this doesn't help, then you might be better off calling a travel agent...

Comment: thanks, I did not know about the time bars feature. If there is no better solution for this problem, then I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

**https://travelgam.com/** is a site meant for exactly this purpose. 
Users can define start of weekend and end of weekend in terms of both day and time.
Such as Friday late evening and Monday early morning respectively.

[image: travelgam]

Outbound and Return times can be specified along with an option for "Direct flights only".