# Cheapest flight "from any city"

Tags: flight-search-engines, fares

*NB the suggested dupe has no working answers. note that the answers here so far are fabulous and work in 2018*

I was just looking at flights **from "North America"** to ICN (Seoul, Korea); I observe that the price varies greatly depending on your departure city.

So, LA (seems to be) drastically cheaper than SF, Vancouver is different again, etc.  The price difference can be very dramatic.

In some contexts it's possible to choose "where you leave from" (imagine you're doing a lot of business travel, or incorporating other visits, etc).

In fact, is there a site that finds the cheapest fares in this concept?

- I really haven't found a QA about this on here
- (I notice, the answers to fare-engine questions seem to change dramatically over time anyway.  Would be good to know a solution for these days, 2018!)

So, "From which city in the US is the cheapest flights to ICN?"  Or any similar "any part of country X to..." search.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flight Search from anywhere to a specific destination](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73709/flight-search-from-anywhere-to-a-specific-destination)

Comment: NB the suggested dupe has no working answers. the suggested dupe has no working answers.

Comment: What about https://www.kiwi.com/en/search/north-america/incheon-international-seoul-south-korea/2018-05-01_2018-05-31/2-10 is not working? (updated link for North America and all of May, stay length adjustable.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google flights gives you a limit of 5 departure airports, while ITA Matrix https://matrix.itasoftware.com/ does not.

Steps:

1. Select some central departure airport, click "nearby" and tick all airports you want to query.
   [image]
2. Set destination and set "calendar of lowest fares" option
   [image]
   Result: a table for all days of the month linking any selected (i.e. US airport) to ICN. 
   [image]
   **Caveat**: some airlines, mostly low-cost carriers are not found in ITA matrix (but they show up in Google flights). Depending on your route, this may have a significant impact.

Comment: wow nice one, sweet

Comment: Matrix has a maximum of 500 results it will return.  If you search for more than a few airports then it will miss results.  eg, I picked May 16 and searched ORD-ICN and found a flight for $696 - over $200 less than your results show for that day.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, skyscanner has such an option (disclaimer: I never used it and have no idea on how cheap/convenient it is). You simply type US in From field (and select 'United States' from suggestions list) and ICN in To, and choose 'Whole month - May' as departure/return date.

https://www.skyscanner.net/transport/flights/us/icn?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&oym=1805&iym=1805

I suspect other widely used search aggregators do as well.

Comment: bounty for answer which works great today, 2019 !  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use Google Flights: https://www.google.com.br/flights.

It's not *exactly* what you're looking for, but you can select lots of citys to depart from to one or more destination.

As an example: 
Depart from: NYC, LA, SF.
To: ICN.

You can mark flights and see the price variation on a daily basis.

In some cases, you can even book the flight through it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: intriguing, you can **click plus and add more than one city!**  Good one

Comment: @Fattie yep, forgot to mention the plus part, but that's exactly what i meant. :)

Answer (score 2):

[Kiwi.com's radius search](https://www.kiwi.com/en/search/41.779--116.698-1000km/seoul-south-korea,busan-south-korea,cheongju-international-cheongju-south-korea,daegu-international-daegu-south-korea,wonju-wonju-south-korea/2019-05-01_2019-06-30?sortBy=price) is an excellent option. The maximum radius doesn't cover a whole continent but it's pretty big (e.g. can cover the US West Coast). Combine that with a string of multiple destinations:

[image: Screenshot of kiwi.com radius search to Korea]

If you are looking flights that include a connection, do note that some of the flights they sell are [budget connections that have different risks](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/134484/what-does-the-kiwi-com-guarantee-cover) than "normal" flights.

Comment: This is your regular Kiwi warning: read this [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/131162/4188) and this [comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/131138/connection-time-at-newark-liberty-intl-airport/131162#comment324583_131141) before jumping on a "kiwi guarantee" connection.

Comment: "The Kiwi guarantee is iffy at best. The max they will do is to refund the price of the missed leg and even that requires jumping through a lot of hoops. They will not get you to your final destination"

Comment: Absolutely, it's good to understand the risk of "virtual interlining." Even if you disregard these "Kiwi guarantee" connections or even just use the site to search and book elsewhere: it's a powerful search tool.

Comment: Sure it is but the regular warning needs to be given because not everyone reads this whole site.