# Routes from each airport

Tags: airlines, routes

Is there a resource out there similar to this
https://www.kayak.com/routes/LAX/201808

That will show a total number of direct routes from any given airport? ideally domestic and international seperate?

in list not a map

Comment: possibly this may help you .. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112443

Answer (score 2):

You can call the API directly and get the result as a JSON document:

https://www.kayak.com/s/run/routes/api?airport=LAX&tm=201808

[image]

Comment: That's perfect, do they have a range or API's? I can't seem to find their API reference page