# Flight plan with multiple airlines

Tags: air-travel, airlines, bangkok, seoul

Is it possible to plan a travel with combination of multiple airlines?

For example I want a round travel from Seoul to Dhaka. For that I want to book a trip(round) for Seoul to Bangkok (date: 2016-09-17 to 2016-10-17) with AirAsia  and another trip(round) for Bangkok to Dhaka (date: 2016-09-18 to 2016-10-16, this dates depends on the first booking) with Thaiair. I want to know whether this is possible or not, if possible then how?

Comment: I mean how the agent will do this? Is there any website or online service for this. And the vital issue is Do I need a Thailand visa for this sort of booking?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. It's common to have flights on multiple airlines on a single ticket, but it's not clear from your question *why* you'd want to fly ICN-BKK-DAC-BKK-ICN in this way, or *why* you need it all on a single ticket. Please [edit](http://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/78267/edit) your post to explain what it is you're trying to do. If you have questions about visas, we also need to know what nationality passport you will be traveling on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do a "broad" search for flights?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/730/how-can-i-do-a-broad-search-for-flights)

Comment: @choster I expect it's because AirAsia is a low cost carrier and so you can't have those segments on the same booking with any other airline.

Comment: I *think* the OP is asking about using back-to-back tickets.

Comment: Yeah, that's what he's doing. I'm not sure why; it would probably be more expensive that way than simply buying a regular ticket, (e.g. a $710 ICN-DAC return from China Eastern, or whoever) _and_ it would require the landside transit in Bangkok, _and_ it carries the risk of missing the connection.

Answer (score 2):

You can not connect Air Asia flights and Thai Airways flights on a single booking nor a single check in.  But there is nothing really preventing you from using two separate bookings for a trip.

Air Asia is a point to point carrier, flying people only on their own aircraft. They do offer "FlyThru", which connects bags on some international routes, but that is ONLY Air Asia to Air Asia, not Air Asia to another carrier.

And flying through Bangkok means two different airports, as Air Asia flies via the older Don Muang Airport and Thai from the main Suvarnabhumi Airport.  So in both directions you will need to clear immigration, claim your bags, clear customs, transfer by bus or taxi between the airports and check in for your next flight.

Whether you need a visa or can enter under the Visa Exempt program depends on your citizenship.