# Looking for search-engine with flexible dates and single airline operated for layovers.

Tags: online-resources, airports, flight-search-engines

I have been looking for a search-engine which can do the following route India to Montreal (Montréal–Pierre Elliott Trudeau International Airport - YUL) . I had been trying to have the following functionality in the search-engine -

a. Give the best prices for the month, let's say Departure in December 2016 and arrival in January 2016 (dates are/can be somewhat flexi) although my travelling dates are somewhat different.

b. Costs should be in INR

c. Both the flights should be preferably operated by the same carrier.

d. some sort of price graph to have some sort of historical data.

I tried three servics, azair of US, akbartravels.net  and couple of other search-engine sites but neither of them were fulfilling all the obligations.

Comment: Are you aware of [this thread](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/730/32134)? - there's plenty of options there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with https://www.kayak.com ? I believe you can do what you need with this one.