# Flexible-date flight search engine with specified weekdays

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, flight-search-engines

I would like to search for cheap flights for a week-end out, without specific restrictions on dates or destinations. Is there a flight search engine that allows one to search for all flights leaving from city X to an unspecified/flexible location on an (also unspecified/flexible) Friday evening and returning on the next Sunday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure this can be done: have a look to [azair](http://www.azair.com/) which has very powerful search options (see the advanced options), **including choice of return and departure day**, length of stay, period within which the trip should happen and a range of departure and arrival airports **including "take me anywhere."**

[image]

A similarly powerful search option for the **anywhere** part is [kiwi.com](https://kiwi.com/en/).

[image]

Note: much of this is copied from [my own answer here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/62626/32134), plus you might want to take note of [this overview of flight search engines I once composed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/62685/32134).

Comment: @pnuts which wiki are we talking about?

Answer (score 1):

With Skyscanner you can search for flights from a city to any particular destination. You could manually search through every upcoming weekend like [this](https://www.skyscanner.com.au/transport/flights-from/psa/161125/161127/cheapest-flights-from-pisa-in-november-2016.html?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=1&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false).

I'm not aware of a flight search engine that allows you to show a list of these flight searches all at once.