# Cheapest country to arrive in Europe without causing citizenship issues

Tags: air-travel, europe, eu, eu-citizens

I'm a dual US/French citizen. I've only rarely been to France, but I'm looking to change that next month spending a few weeks traveling around the country and the European continent.

Because of freedom of movement, I know I can arrive anywhere in "Europe" without the need for a visa, but in practice are there any countries that will be more difficult to arrive at? More importantly, given I'll be traveling around the continent anyway, so my location of arrival isn't particularly important, what are the cheapest countries/cities to fly to and from the US, that are connected to the rail system?

Comment: Any research from your side done, regarding your travel ?

Comment: This question is on the broad side. Difficult in terms of what? Strictness of customs officials? Availability of ATMs? And which rail system? All the major transatlantic gateways in Europe except DUB have rail service, but not all have the train station in the terminal, and options vary across the full range— Metro, commuter rail, intercity service, high-speed, etc.

Comment: If you have a valid French passport and the picture still resembles you, no place in the EU or the Schengen area **should** give you troubles. You are not asking for the privilege of entering. You are exercising your treaty **rights**.

Comment: You can arrive in any EU country without "citizenship issues," assuming proper documentation, as you are an EU citizen. I don't see how we can answer the "cheapest" question. Airfares vary wildly depending on where you're flying from and the dates in question, and we don't know where on the continent you plan to go. You might want to see our question [How can I do a “broad” search for flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/730/how-can-i-do-a-broad-search-for-flights), which has some tips on searching for airfares under broad conditions like this.

Comment: @DumbCoder significant research, especially concerning travel by rail and legal rights. But travel in practice rarely goes by the book

Comment: Research might include reading real world experiences.

Comment: Especially from the West Coast don't forget to check Oslo -- while not in the EU, freedom of movement applies. Norwegian flies to LAX, OAK, seasonally LAS and then on to Europe practically anywhere for cheap.

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist "But travel in practice rarely goes by the book" In this case it does, at least at airports (in my experience) - if you present a valid passport or *carte d'identité* and they try to question your right to enter, that is technically misconduct (unless they think the document is fake) and you're fully within your rights to raise it with a supervisor.

Comment: If you are a threat to public safety or public health, or if you are undesirable for reasons of public policy, then you should fly directly to France because other EU countries might refuse to admit you.  Otherwise, you may exercise your right of freedom of movement in the EU by showing your French passport or identity card, not only in theory but also in practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can arrive in any EU country without 'citizenship issues' (i.e. without visa) on the basis of either US or French passport for a stay of up to a few months. Cost of living varies and you can research it. All countries are connected to France by rail (except Ireland). Cost of getting to France by rail is roughly proportional to distance.

That should let you work out the details.

Comment: Some countries may act as a better experience for an overall experience on entry, for example if you fly into a non-Schengen participating country (e.g. the UK or Ireland), you end up having to prove entry eligibility twice - once for entry into that country, and then once more for entry into Schengen.  If you flew directly into a Schengen participant, you have the potential for fewer immigration checks...

Comment: @Moo Presumably you wouldn't go through UK immigration if you booked a flight from the US to France via the UK, so it would be pretty much the same. A flight to the UK, followed by the train to France is a possibility, but almost certainly not the fastest or cheapest or most logical one unless you actually plan to spend time in the UK first, at which point passing through UK immigration is mandatory anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure that Greece is readily connected by rail to France unless you want to do a trans-European rail trip involving half dozen long transfers.

Scandinavian and Baltic states aren't very well connected by rail with the continental EU.