# Finding the cheapest flight from a given airport to anywhere in a given country

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, flight-search-engines

There exist many search engines to find the cheapest  flight between two airports. Is there any way to find the cheapest flight from a given  airport to anywhere in a given country?

I am mostly interested in flying to a French territory, which has many airports, so it's tedious to explicitly list all of them in a multi-destination search:

[image]

Comment: Does said country have so many feasible airports that you can't just list them explicitly in a multi-destination search?  That's the first thing I would tend to try.

Comment: @NateEldredge yes France many airports, I added a map in the question.

Comment: Oh I see - I thought you meant a specific French territory, but you mean all of France including its overseas parts.

Comment: @NateEldredge correct, sorry I now realize my phasing was ambiguous

Comment: You want to visit any part of France including territories? That's not a normal travel search case at all. Search engines aren't normally built for someone who wants to look for a trip to Paris or, say, French Guiana  at the same time, because that's not a thing many people ever want to search for. That said, you could probably try collecting the airport codes yourself and putting them all in the ITA Matrix destination field. Then sort by price on various dates.

Comment: @ZachLipton it's for a common travel reason, which I'll keep off record. I'd prefer to avoid coding :)

Comment: There are some hints [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/730/how-can-i-do-a-broad-search-for-flights) about searches for all flights to a country, though my guess is that will only cover metropolitan France.  If your origin is in Europe that will almost certainly be the cheapest.  If you're outside Europe I bet your choices will be either CDG or whatever few overseas areas are on your continent.

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks, I often move around for conferences, and France had many territories, so I'd prefer to have a more automated approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with [the list of the busiest airports in France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_busiest_airports_in_France), including territories and overseas departments. It's likely that this omits particularly far-flung destinations, and if you really want to be thorough, you could manually audit the list against [every airport in France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_in_France) (clicking into the sub-lists for territories) for those with regular commercial service. This is left as an exercise for the reader. But unless you happen to already be nearby, a small island airport with less than 20,000 passengers/year is not going to be the cheapest flight option anyway.

Use your browser to vertically select the list of IATA codes for all 77 airports (if your browser doesn't do this, Firefox does). Copy.

[image: list of IATA codes]

Use the text processing tool of your choice to turn that into a comma separated list.

[image: find and replace]

Enjoy this list of airport codes:

```
CDG,ORY,NCE,LYS,MRS,TLS,MLH,BOD,NTE,BVA,PTP,RUN,FDF,LIL,MPL,AJA,PPT,SXB,BIA,BIQ,BES,PUF,TLN,FSC,RNS,NOU,CAY,GEA,CFE,CCF,LDE,PGF,DZA,CLY,GNB,LIG,EGC,BOB,ETZ,BZR,CMF,LRH,RFP,FNI,SFG,TUF,LIF,SBH,EBU,LRT,RDZ,HUH,DLE,CFR,DOL,DNR,PIS,UIP,XCR,ILP,MOZ,UVE,MEE,RGI,ZSE,BVE,DCM,AGF,TIH,WLS,NHV,LAI,AUR,AUQ,MAU,FAV,SNR
```

Pop over to [ITA Matrix](https://matrix.itasoftware.com) and construct your search, using your preferred origin, dates, and other preferences, and pasting in the list of airports in the destination field:

[image: ITA matrix search]

Sort by price and enjoy the results:

[image: ITA matrix results]

You can also use the "see calendar of lowest fares" option if you don't have a particular date in mind, though it will take a while.

Comment: SFO to CDG for 301 USD, this month. That's pretty impressive. :)

Comment: @MastaBaba That's a one-way, but yeah, the XL Airways flights are really cheap right now. I also don't know anyone who's ever flown on one, which might be why they're so cheap.

Comment: @MastaBaba Maybe they charge another $150 for the seat and $250 for checked luggage.

Comment: I confirmed the price in that's inclusive of taxes. Didn't check for seat and luggage, but, either way, that's indeed dirt cheap. I wish tickets from South America to Europe where that cheap. :)

Answer (score 2):

The search engine for this is [Adioso.com](http://adioso.com). They allow you to specify a destination airport, city, region, country, group of countries (like 'western Europe') and continent.

But... I'm not so sure whether even they would accept something like 'any French territory anywhere in the world'... They do accept 'French Southern Territories', but I couldn't get a flight result for that.

Comment: "French Southern Territories" refers to a bunch of uninhabited islands near Antarctica, so you're not going to find any commercial flights there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Southern_and_Antarctic_Lands