# How can I see the different flight costs to the different cities of the continental US for a specific date?

Tags: usa, air-travel, flight-search-engines

I want to hop on a plane next Thursday and return on Sunday. It doesn't matter *that much* where I go, as long as it's relatively cheap.

Comment: why would you want to take a plane for such a short time, especially if you don't care where you go? (and does it have to be a plane? what about trains, buses, ships?)

Comment: @njzk2: [FlixBus US has a long-distance coach network](https://www.flixbus.com/bus-routes) with some overnight trips (reclining seats, wifi; limits on hand-luggage). In the OP's case they could leave Wednesday night and return late Sunday. (Their website doesn't make it easy to see all the journey times, depature times and fares from a single departure station.) There is also Craiglist rideshare, at your own risk.

Comment: While this wasn't part of your original constraint, you may also want to filter for total travel time, otherwise you may end up with recommended flights where you have 6 hours at your destination before you turn around to go home.

Answer (score 10):

Google flights can do this if you set the destination to "Anywhere" and than zoom in on the map to your area of interest. Below are all flights from Boston for your dates.

Many other websites offer the same feature (Kayak, Syscanner, etc) but I find Google interface convenient since you can apply useful filters to narrow your search.

[image]

Comment: This top level image is a bit misleading.  It shows Santa Fe  (SAF) as a destination with a $842 price tag.  But SAF is a small regional airport that has limited connectivity.  Unless you have a particular reason to use it, you are much better off flying into Albuquerque, which is a much larger airport, has a lot more connections, is a lot cheaper to fly to, and is only 1 hour down the road from SAF.  So based on initial price you'd discount taking a trip to Santa Fe.

Comment: [Santa Fe Airport pictures in our photo contest](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8572/october-2023-photo-contest-unexpected-perspective/8579#8579)

Answer (score 8):

There are probably lots of tools which allow you to do this, but for instance in Google Flights:

- Enter your departure airport
- Enter “USA” as destination
- Select your departure and return dates

You probably want to then add filters such as “nonstop only”.

You can then get results in list or map format.

Answer (score 3):

I've found Kayak to be quite good at this as well. [This is the link](https://www.kayak.com/explore/ORL-anywhere/20231116,20231119) for a Thursday-Sunday flight from Orlando to anywhere.

There are a few filters.  And you can use North America, Florida, etc as destinations to zoom the map as well.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

One can use [Kiwi](https://www.kiwi.com/en/search/tiles/vancouver-british-columbia-canada/united-states/2023-12-20/no-return?sortAggregateBy=price), see screenshots below.

FYI:

- [Finding the cheapest flight from a given airport to anywhere in a given country](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/101335/1810).
- [What potential issues may arise from using the Kiwi online travel agency?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/184695/1810)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not my downvote but Kiwi is probably one of the more questionable OTAs.

Comment: Kiwi has a terrible reputation, so you probably want to preamble this with "you may like use their search engine for discovery, but I don't recommend actually booking with them".

Comment: @smci done, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: but not here in comments, I recommended adding something like that *in the answer text*. so it gets, read, seen, indexed by search engine (both SO and Google), and the words *"I don't recommend actually booking with them"* get seen by search engine, it doesn't just interpret this mention as an endorsement.