# Is there a site with a list of active airline discount/coupon codes?

Tags: budget, online-resources, airlines

Ideally I'm after one with an alphabetical list of airlines, and available discount codes, with descriptions, without having to click through and manually check the conditions of each one, or test out the reliability and so on.

Answer (score 5):

I know that you have already [answered this in a different question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/195/108), TravelZoo - *separate* from its Top 20 deals of the week newsletter - also [lists ongoing flight deals from airlines](http://www.travelzoo.com/uk/cheap-flights/). I've found this to be a fairly comprehensive list; however, they are typically not provided in the form of 'discount codes' as such but a list of promotional airfares on offer by any airline in the form of "starting from price X".

Comment: I was going to point out that TravelZoo tends to just have a 'top 20' list of deals for the week, then noticed the second part of your answer.  It's a start, but I was hoping for discount codes.  For example, until recently you could use 'NewYear200' on AirNewZealand.com to get discounts on flights from the UK.  My search continues :/

Comment: Unfortunately that "Best Flight Deals" page only seems to exist for the UK edition.  The Top 20 is available in all countries served by TravelZoo though.